How does active funds mimic index and also incur large tax expenses?
I'm reading the The Permanent Portfolio, in one chapter it talks about using index funds to have exposure on stocks.

For investors with significant holdings in taxable accounts, tax
efficiency is an important consideration. A fund that is tax efficient
is managed so that it generates as little taxable income as possible
for its shareholders each year. As with all expenses, tax costs add up
over time, and thus tax efficiency should be a consideration when
designing an investment strategy. As it happens, index funds are the
most tax-efficient stock fund you can own. They do not have managers
actively trading stocks and generating unnecessary taxes behind the
scenes.
Table 6.6 shows how index funds have fewer taxes by comparing two
leading index funds with the Fidelity Magellan fund (Ticker: FMAGX).
The Fidelity Magellan fund is a popular, actively managed fund that
largely mirrors the S&P 500 and Total Stock Market funds due to its
size, but actively trades stocks in a (failed) attempt to beat these indexes.

My questions,

If the fund manager is mimicking an index, e.g S&P 500, why would they also try to do active trading?
Suppose the fund never pays dividends, only increases the net worth when the stock value rises, do they still have to pay taxes when a trade is executed? Or should the investor pay the tax when they sell shares of the fund?


Perhaps what the quote means is that, while the Magellan fund performance roughly mirrors the overall market, after expenses and exercised capital gains in excess of passive investing they fail to beat the passive index?

keshlam has addressed 1. Regarding


Suppose the fund never pays dividends, only increases the net worth when the stock value rises, do they still have to pay taxes when a trade is executed? Or should the investor pay the tax when they sell shares of the fund?


this is essentially impossible for a US fund, which is the type Browne was writing about. And your quote

... index funds are the most tax-efficient stock fund you can own. They do not have managers actively trading stocks and generating unnecessary taxes behind the scenes.

although literally true, glosses over the necessary taxes. Specifically, a US mutual fund:

must distribute substantially all its investment income (dividends from stocks and/or interest from bonds) net of operating expenses, to shareholders who must report it as taxable income, or else the fund must pay an additional tax which reduces its return compared to comparable funds, and since investors prefer the funds with higher returns, such a fund goes out of business. While the tax code only requires distribution by the end of the year, because dividend or interest income and operating expenses are generally steady and mostly predictable, many funds distribute quarterly or even monthly.

must either distribute at least yearly substantially all its realized gains net of realized losses for the year, or else pay a fund-level tax and impute both the undistributed gain and the tax on it to shareholders, most of whom would have paid lower taxes on on a distributed gain, so again they abandon this fund and it goes out of business. To avoid distributing gains that might be cancelled by subsequent losses, most funds do this distribution in Dec (if at all). However an ETF, as opposed to a traditional book-issue fund, generally does not realize gains or losses itself because it trades in-kind to and from authorized participants who create and redeem ETF shares as needed to fill or drain the market, and thus does not need to make such a distribution.


Now, the S&P500 is composed of large-cap stocks, many of which are dividend payers, while an index fund generally has very low expenses, so an S&P500 index fund will nearly always have net income to distribute -- although since these are US companies usually most of this income constitutes 'qualified' dividends that are taxed at lower rates (as long as you hold for at least 61 days including the ex-div date; in case of some preferred stock this is increased to 91 days but you won't find that in an S&P500 index).
As above an ETF normally will not have net gains to distribute; a book-issue S&P500 fund won't trade very much due to index changes but may need to trade because of inflows and outflows, which often will result in net realized gains which are taxed as above.
And as you indicate when you sell fund shares at a gain that is taxable. Unless you die; then your estate needs to pay tax only above a pretty high threshold, and your heirs get the shares with 'stepped-up' basis. However, few people consider dying a good investment strategy; it interferes significantly with you enjoying the use of the profits, and even worse, it's very hard to do it in more than one tax year.

Managed funds do not track an index. They actively trade  stocks, buying and selling wherever the manager sees what they consider an opportunity. Theoretically, if the manager is sufficiently insightful and lucky, this lets them produce higher returns. In practice, the additional costs of active trading, plus the cost of paying for the manager's efforts, burn enough of that profit that these funds have trouble actually achieving better results than an index fund with its lower costs.

Active Fund managers don't try to imitate or track an index (such as the S&P 500 index), but for very large Active Funds, the managers are forced into holding stocks that are not too different from the stocks comprising some index.  This is because mutual fund managers are also under various restrictions such as not investing more than x% of its assets in one stock, or not more than y% in some sectors, or holding more than z% of the outstanding shares in any one company etc. In the mid-1980s, Fidelity Magellan was managing $14 billion and was invested in 1400 stocks.
